# I want a regex support for characters that uses IP Address with Subnet

Tags: regex, ip-address, ipv4, subnet, regex-alternation

I have a regex  `^[a-zA-Z0-9.*?]+$` that supports IP addresses like `31.202.216.280` how can I modify the given regex in a way where I could support subnets with an IP address like so `31.202.216.280/38`

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, if you set `[0-9]` for the Blocks, you can type an IPAddress with `999` as number.

If you want to "limit" to the **0-255 numbers**, you need to explicit do this with:

```
^
(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\/
([1-3][0-2]$|[0-2][0-9]$|0?[0-9]$)
```

Makes it possible to write addresses with:
`(0-255).(0-255).(0-255).(0-255)/(0-32)`

Answer (score 0):

Look at the pre-made regular expressions provided by these Perl modules.

[Regexp::Common::net](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common::net)

[Regexp::Common::net::CIDR](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common::net::CIDR)

You can use them on the command line or from a Perl script.  You can also just copy the regex's and use them in another language.

Answer (score 0):

With such a regex for IPs you might catch a lot of false positive. Try at least to remove `a-ZA-Z`. There are already great regex on SO to match IPs.

If you want to match your subnet add `/[0-9]{1,3}` before your string end (`$`). You might need to escape the slash depending on your programming language: `\/`.

Answer (score 0):

if with regex subnet

```
^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\/[0-9]{1,3}$
```

if without subnet you may try

```
^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$
```

[image: by josuamarcelc]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ttp template to capture IPs and PREFIXs as following. `|IP` captures IPs, `|PREFIX` captures prefixs.

See the following ttp example:

```
ttp_template = """
{{Prefix|PREFIX}}
{{Ip|IP}}
"""
```